# How to set a listener function for a button defined programatically in swift 3

Tags: ios, button, uibutton, swift3

I am trying to set a listener function for my button but I keep getting error . Here is how've done it :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //Create the BackGround
       self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        let startButton = UIButton()
        startButton.setTitle( " start ", for: UIControlState.normal)
        startButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
        startButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y:40 , width: 250, height: 25)
        self.view.addSubview(startButton)

        startButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:" , for: .touchUpInside)


    }


    func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("hello")
    }


}
```

Does any one knows where am I making the mistake ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. Just replace

```
startButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:" , for: .touchUpInside)
```

with this:

```
startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonPressed(sender:)) , for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Well based on my understanding the only part that needed to be changed was the action part ? right ? how ever once I replaced it with your example it tells me that there is no member called buttonPressed for the type viewController how ever there is no difference in the typing :)

Comment: Oops, in your case it should be buttonPressed(sender:) according to your method signature. Please try an updated answer